# Floated elements gaps between but no explicit padding/margin

Tags: html, css

I have the below markup that cannot be changed:

```
<div>Some data</div>
<span>More data</span>
<a>Link 1</a>
<a>Link 2</a>
```

I want it to appear rendered so that the div is all the way to the left and the span is all the way to the right whilst links 1 and 2 are to the right of the span.

Meaning:

```
|<div>                   <span><a1><a2>|
```

Where |'s indicate the edge of the containing div.

I can get the below with float left on the div and float right on the other elements but you can see this is not exactly what I want.

```
|<div>                   <a2><a1><span>|
```

Given that the data in the span will not always be the same size a fixed margin/padding won't work.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty close:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, div { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#outer { margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; background: yellow; overflow: hidden; text-align: right; }
#outer div { float: left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
<div>Some data</div>
<span>More data</span>
<a>Link 1</a>
<a>Link 2</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The containing element is a block level element and thus as wide as it needs to be. Set the text alignment to right and the inline elements go to the right in the correct order. A float left on the first div keeps it on the left.